# Prove that Möbius strip deformation retracts to a circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces, retraction

I am trying to prove the following claim:

> The following topological space, up to homeomorphism, is called the Möbius strip:
> $$M=[0,1]/\sim$$
> where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $(0,t)\sim (1,1-t)$. Then $M$ deformation retracts to a circle.

Let $I=[0,1]$ and consider the map $F:I^2\times I\to I^2$ given by:
$$F(r,s;t)=(r,tr+(1-t)s)$$
It is clear that $F$ is a deformation retract of $I^2$ to the diagonal $D=\{(r,r):r\in I\}$. It we pass to the quotient $M$ we get a continuous map $\tilde F:M\times I\to M$ given by:
$$\tilde F([(r,s)],t)=[F(r,s;t)]$$

My question is:

> How can I prove that $\tilde F$ is continuous?

Comment: Your quotation does not define the Möbius strip (which is a quotient of $I^2$, not $I$).

Comment: I think you need to pick an open Nbd of $M$, then we have $2$ cases to consider. The open Nbd not containing the boundary points and the open Nbd containing the boundary points. I think drawing a square should help.